# Filling up a hand with random cards that are not yet drawn - Monte Carlo

Tags: c++, random, simulation, ai

I would like to know if there is a more efficient way to speed up below code. This function is meant to fill in a set of poker hand with the remaining 
cards using Mersenne Twister for a Monte Carlo simulation.

```
void HandEvaluator::RandomFill(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Card>>& _Set, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Card>>& _Dead, unsigned int _Target){
    //Add the cards that are currently in Set as dead cards
    for (auto const& CardInSet : _Set)
    {
        if (CardInSet == nullptr)
            break;

        _Dead.push_back(CardInSet);
    }

    bool IsDead;
    unsigned int RequiredAmt = _Target - _Set.size();

    unsigned int CardIndex = 0;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int> CardsDistribution(0, 51);

    for (unsigned int Index = 0; Index < RequiredAmt; Index++)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            IsDead = false;
            CardIndex = CardsDistribution(MTGenerator);

            for (auto const& Dead : _Dead)
            {
                if (ReferenceDeck[CardIndex]->GetRank() == Dead->GetRank() && ReferenceDeck[CardIndex]->GetSuit() == Dead->GetSuit())
                {
                    IsDead = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!IsDead)
            {
                _Set.push_back(ReferenceDeck[CardIndex]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Visual Studio Profiler had identified that this line

```
    CardIndex = CardsDistribution(MTGenerator);
```

is the main culprit behind the high compute time. Is Mersenne Twister itself not meant for a Monte Carlo Simulation and another PRNG should be used instead ? Or there are some inefficient lines that I had missed out ?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to CodeReview! I reformatted your code section. Next time, please just paste the code, select it, then press Ctrl + K.

Comment: Could you please also post other parts of the code used in the post? A little example program which can be compiled and run would be awesome! Don't be concerned with size of the program, 100-200 lines of code is common for a CR question.

Comment: Thanks for the help ! I've done up a sample project that can be compiled and run. However, my sample project relies on a relatively large .dat file (~126mb) to perform the simulation.  Should I include the .dat file into the project and upload them into a file storage site like Google Drive or include another project that generate .dat file?

Comment: Whichever is more convenient for you. People might want to check their modifications, like comparing the output of your version and their version. I believe the code you've shown here just generates the deck of cards. Maybe you could include all of the code used for it and create a small main function which generates one deck and prints it? For example, at the moment I don't know what `Card` is (I can guess that it is either an integer or pair which represents a card) and what is `ReferenceDeck` (vector of cards?).

Comment: Ah sorry for the confusion, this function is meant to generate a hand, `_Target` amt of cards, based on the remaining cards in a deck. The generation of ReferenceDeck is in another part of the `HandEvaluator` class and `Card` is a class that contains the `Suit` and `Rank` with functions to compare with other `Card`s. Here's the link to the sample project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U3d8ZuS_wzkq4RVIj2RV6gj1zyv_yrco/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi! On attempt to run the code, I get segfault where the code tries to generate score for opponents, specifically in the line with many nested `HR` accesses. Upon further investigation, I found that the value yielded by `HR[53 + CardInts[0]]` is very large and thus outside of bounds. I've rewritten most of the code without changing the logic (at least I hope so), could you please help me out with getting it to run? Here is the link for [my version](https://github.com/simmplecoder/cards-monte-carlo.git). Sorry for taking so long, dates of my finals were quite spread out.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, really appreciate the optimizations you made. It seems that your version returns a different result from mine. After some digging, it seems that you had changed `HR` to a `std::vector`. I tried to change it back to an array but a 'Stack Overflow' exception was thrown which had never happen in my main project. I assume that's the reason for your change to `std::vector`.

Comment: you can allocate the object on the heap, as you did previosly, using unique pointer. Did it get faster? Is my version worth fixing? May I also ask how I can generate input data myself?

Comment: I tried to test the `DetermineValue_7Card` function from your version with a sample hand of `4c, Ah, 4h, 3h, Kd, Qh, Js`, the last access to `HR`, specifically `HR[HR[HR[HR[HR[HR[.....] + CardInts[5]]`, returns a `0` while mine returns a value of `24727680`. I believe this is the cause for our different results but I not sure about the reason for its occurrence.

Comment: Your version does get significantly faster than mine, at least 40% ! I will implement your optimization into my main project. To generate the input data, download this [library](http://web.archive.org/web/20130315225827/http://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/poker-hand-evaluator-roundup#xpokereval) . Within it, there is a table generation code in XPokerEval.TwoPlusTwo project. Build and run that project will produce the .DAT file.

Comment: Hey, I managed to implement the changes into my main project. The cause of the weird behavior of `DetermineValue_7Card` is due to `RandomFill` generating invalid cards. Instead of using `std::find` in `RandomFill`, `std::find_if` should be used as the `std::find` compared the `Card` using the default `==` operator that does not perform the actual comparison of the `Suit` and `Rank`. Once I fixed that, I can see a significant improvement in performance. I can't really upvote or tick your comment but I appreciate your help !

Comment: I'm a bit unsure what you mean. I had some other optimizations which I'd like to perform, but cannot get it to run due to the error you described. Implementation of `operator==` looks correct to me. What comparison you had in mind?

Comment: The implementation is correct. The issue is that `std::find` is not using the`operator==` from `Card` class but is instead using the default `operator==` from `std` namespace. There is an explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287224/why-isnt-stdfind-using-my-operator). Since the default `operator==` cannot compare the `Suit` and `Rank` between 2 `Card`, this results in `std::find` returning invalid `Card`

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I opt to replace Mersenne Twister with another PRNG, [xoroshiro128+](http://vigna.di.unimi.it/xorshift/xoroshiro128plus.c), it managed to cut the compute time by around 15%. I also did some minor optimization on the for-loop but the improvement is minuscule. Anyway, here is the same function but with new PRNG:

Seeding in `HandEvaluator`'s constructor:

```
HandEvaluator::HandEvaluator()
{
    Initialize();
    MTGenerator.seed(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());

    s[0] = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    std::cout << "Seed 1: " << s[0] << "\n";

    s[1] = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    std::cout << "Seed 2: " << s[1] << "\n";
}
```

`HandEvaluator`'s RandomFill function:

```
void HandEvaluator::RandomFill(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Card>>& _Set, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Card>>& _Dead, unsigned int _Target)
{
    //Add the cards that are currently in Set as dead cards
    for (auto const& CardInSet : _Set)
    {
        if (CardInSet == nullptr)
            break;

        _Dead.push_back(CardInSet);
    }

    bool IsDead;
    unsigned int RequiredAmt = _Target - _Set.size();

    for (unsigned int Index = 0; Index < RequiredAmt; Index++)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            _Set.push_back(ReferenceDeck[next() % 52]);

            IsDead = false;

            for (auto const& Dead : _Dead)
            {
                if (Dead->IsEqualTo(_Set[_Set.size() - 1]))
                {
                    IsDead = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (IsDead)
                _Set.pop_back();
            else
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you got rid of the Mersenne Twister you should probably rename `MTGenerator`

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, I had removed `MTGenerator` from `HandEvaluator` class as its no longer necessary